# Permission Error and unable to import PIL.image on jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, keras, jupyter-notebook

I have to apply this code for computer vision project https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-load-train-and-test-data-from-the-local-drive-for-a-deep-learning-Keras-model which is load train and test data from the local drive for Keras model.
I was tried but appears some errors such as:

`PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-3806351fb2b0> in <module>
     14 for sample in train_batch:
     15         img_path = train_path+sample
---> 16         x = image.load_img(img_path)
     17         # preprocessing if required
     18         x_train.append(x)`

`~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    108         raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
    109                           'The use of`load_img`requires PIL.')
--> 110     img = pil_image.open(path)
    111     if color_mode == 'grayscale':
    112         if img.mode != 'L':`

`~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2768 
   2769     if filename:
-> 2770         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2771         exclusive_fp = True
   2772`

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\step2_dir/datasets/dataset/Alfalfa'`

Note: I already sure about installed PIL successfully.

So, I need some help if anyone can try to apply the code and tell me how to fix the errors.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question to include your errors (not as image).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the permission to access the filepath:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\step2_dir/datasets/dataset/Alfalfa
```

Easily solvable! Are you on Windows?

You most likely open jupyter notebook from a Powershell, you just have to open a shell with administrator rights (right-click on cmd and/or powershell --> Run as administrator).

If you are on a bash shell run jupyter notebook as a superuser, and you will have the permission needed:

```
sudo jupyter notebook
```

Comment: I have changed train_batch to x_train and everything was fixed *_<